# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Moniczka' occured when I tried to register new user in REST API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, registration, endpoint

I created registration API view using Django REST API and when I tried to use endpoint, after POST I could have seen the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Moniczka'. I've checked RegisterSerializer, RegisterAPI view and url and I can't see any mistakes. Mayby some of you can help me.

Here is my serializer class:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'],
                    validated_data['password'])
        return user
```

Here is my views.py:

```
# Register API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user":
            UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token":
            AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })
```

And finally urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', RegisterAPI.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

and traceback from django debug:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.8.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'knox',
 'savings']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\savings\views.py", line 79, in post
    UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "D:\workspace\Money\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 963, in to_representation
    return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/register/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Moniczka'
```

I hope that one of you could help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

> ```
>     user = User(username=validated_data['username'], email=validated_data['email'],
>                 password=validated_data['password'])
> ```

Also, if **User** if regular Django user model (django.contrib.auth.models.User), you should use [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) function to set the password - passing it as a parameter won't work.

> ```
>     user = User(username=validated_data['username'], email=validated_data['email'])
>     user.set_password(validated_data['password']))
> ```